# If you have Visual Studio 2017 Preview 2 update can you provide me with include/iosfwd file?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

I just run into a bug inside Visual Studio 2017 C++ Preview 3; The include file `include/iosfwd` is missing member `seekpos()` in class `fpos`, therefore `boost` no longer compiles with error `error C2039: 'seekpos': is not a member of 'std::fpos<_Mbstatet>'`

Microsoft already knows the issue ( https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/282567/member-seekpos-in-class-fpos-is-missing.html?inRegister=true ) with last update 2 days ago.

By reporter, the file `include/iosfwd` inside VS 2017 Preview 2 is **not** corrupted. But downgrade is impossible.

If you, by any chance, still have VS 2017 Preview 2 can you post that file (located here: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Preview\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\{Build}\include\iosfwd` ) on some gist and post link to it?

The inability to compile boost program is a blocking issue for our project.

Comment: The full source-code of the missing function is provided in the issue you linked. Just put it in the class somewhere.

Comment: @tkausl Thanks! I think I need a new pair of eyes... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it on the linked issue (as solution): https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/282567/member-seekpos-in-class-fpos-is-missing.html?inRegister=true